# Gnome launch item ignoring command line arguments

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

In relation to this question:

[Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal)

I have a launch item on a Gnome desktop whose command is this:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --disable-factory
```

However, when this is launched, it just tells the existing `gnome-terminal` to create another window, as if the argument weren't there. If I launch several terminals, there is only one `gnome-terminal` process.

From the shell, if I run the above command, I get a separate instance; `ps -aux | grep gnome-terminal` shows two processes.

The exact `.desktop` file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gnome Terminal in Separate Process, DAMN IT!
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --disable-factory
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/gnome-window-manager.svg
Categories=Accessories
StartupNotify=false
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.2
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal.xml
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal
```

I'm looking at the documentation for the `Exec` variable and it says that arguments are supported:

http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html#exec-variables

If I try to launch this desktop item, it's just telling the existing Gnome Terminal to fork. And it's not able to do that because that process has a bloated virtual memory footprint, so I get a dialog box saying `There was an error launching the application. Details: Failed to fork (Cannot allocate memory).`  Even in this situation, in an existing terminal, I can easily run `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --disable-factory` to get a new terminal window, with no fork failure.