# How to cause copies of executables to open as separate processes?

Tags: linux, process

I want to have renamed copies of some executables use different processes when executed.

System: Lubuntu 18.04 Desktop 64 bit.

For example:

```
$ sudo cp -a /usr/bin/mate-terminal  /usr/bin/mate-terminal-left
$ sudo cp -a /usr/bin/mate-terminal  /usr/bin/mate-terminal-right
```

From a launcher, I execute `mate-terminal-left`, which opens a terminal window on the left-half of the screen (due to my configuration settings for the OpenBox window manager).

Just for reference, I execute the following in that terminal:

```
$ ps -eo pid,command | grep -i 'terminal' | grep -ve 'grep'
19294 /usr/bin/mate-terminal-left
```

Now, with the left terminal still open, from another launcher, I execute `mate-terminal-right`, which should open a terminal window on the right-half of the screen. However, `mate-terminal-right` did not create a new process, but instead used the already active `mate-terminal-left` process, hence it opens on the left as well.

```
$ ps -eo pid,command | grep -i 'terminal' | grep -ve 'grep'
19294 /usr/bin/mate-terminal-left
```

When I open `mate-terminal-right` first, then it opens on the right, and then `mate-terminal-left` will also end up on the right.

I have found that some executables, such as Geany work well for my left and right renaming approach, but other executables such as `mate-terminal` and `pcmanfm` use the same process for all instances, even when started with different names.

My question is: How can I cause `mate-terminal-left` and `mate-terminal-right` to each open as separate processes?

In response to the comments below that suggest how to make a left and right terminal, thanks for your suggestions. However, that is not what my question asks. I only used the example to provide a concrete explanation of why someone might want the same executable running in multiple processes, rather than multiple instances running in the same process. I used `mate-terminal` only as an example, so I am not looking for another terminal.

The title of this question is what I am asking about: "How to cause copies of executables to open as separate processes?"

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407863/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/

Comment: I suggest that you try with another light-weight terminal emulator program, for example: sakura or xterm. It seems xterm starts a separate process for each instance. But you can also use the associated bash process to identify the window. It is possible to use aliases to start terminal windows at specified locations:

Comment: `alias xterm-left='xterm -T 'xterm-left' -geometry +0-0 -fa default -fs 12'`

Comment: `alias xterm-right='xterm -T 'xterm-right' -geometry -0-0 -fa default -fs 12'`

Comment: `alias gterm-left='gnome-terminal --geometry=+0-0'`

Comment: `alias gterm-right='gnome-terminal --geometry=-0-0'`

Comment: 1. Maybe these examples can help you create the terminal windows where you want them; 2. Not only `xterm` but also `sakura` starts a separate process for each instance.

Comment: Here is how to achieve left and right terminals using mate-terminal and Openbox.
In the launcher for the right-hand terminal:
Exec=/usr/bin/mate-terminal --role=mate-terminal-right
In the Openbox configuration file: ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
  <application role="mate-terminal-right">
    <position force="no">
      <x>50%</x>
      <y>0</y>
    </position>
    <size>
      <width>50%</width>
      <height>100%</height>
    </size>
The left hand is similar. I place the two launchers in the top panel for convenience.

Comment: Maybe your concept works with `sakura` because it will run separate processes for each window. It can be installed from the repository `universe`.

Comment: @GaryH. I understand from your edited question, that you are not interested in workarounds, but rather explanations and (if possible) solutions that make programs create separate processes for each instance. Tell me if you want me to remove my comments and my answer (in order to remove clutter).

Comment: @sudous Thank you for your suggestions. As I mentioned in my comment above, I already have the example working with mate-terminal, and I was not looking for a workaround. The information below from Filipe Brandenburger is the exact type of information that I was seeking. I do not think you should remove your information, since it is useful information.

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226465/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing here is fairly specific to `mate-terminal` itself, though more generally using some shared GNOME/GTK+ infrastructure that you might also find in other applications (you mentioned `pcmanfm` as well.)

When you launch a new copy of `mate-terminal`, perhaps from a different binary, it *does* create a new process for it. But `mate-terminal` is programmed to connect to D-Bus and try to look up a "factory", in which case it will pass it the arguments for what to start in the terminal and have the "factory" manage it, then terminate the new process. (If there's no factory, it will register itself as the factory, that's why the first process started will end up managing all terminals.)

The "factory" is found through its D-Bus path, `/org/mate/Terminal/Factory`, which is [hardcoded](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/blob/v1.21.0/src/terminal.c#L46) into the binary. (Thus, replicated into other copies of the binary.)

In the case of `mate-terminal` specifically, you can disable this behavior by passing it a `--disable-factory` command-line argument. (See [the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/mate-terminal/mate-terminal.1.en.html) for more details.)

That's fairly unique to how `mate-terminal` works. In particular, `pcmanfm` doesn't really do this the same way. It's unclear whether `pcmanfm` supports a way to launch a separate process, or if the only way it works is by communicating through D-Bus with an existing instance. (You'd have to look into `pcmanfm` to see if it does.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for. I did not understand what a "factory" was before reading your information. I will mark your answer as being the solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: use a tool that creates separate processes

I have a shellscript, that creates three terminal windows on my main computer's desktop. With some ideas from my script I made the following attempt, which might work for you (or help you make what you need),

```
#!/bin/bash

vdockw=0 #68
hdockw=60

resol=$(xrandr|grep current|cut -d, -f2)
resol=$(<<< "$resol" sed 's/.*current //')
echo $resol
xres=${resol%% *}
yres=${resol##* }
echo $xres $yres
xmid=$(( (xres-vdockw)/2 ))
ymid=$((yres-hdockw))
echo $xmid $ymid

#xterm -title "term v" & pid=$!
sakura --title="term v" & pid=$!
sleep 0.5
wid=$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$pid" | cut "-d " -f1)
sleep 1
echo $pid $wid
wmctrl -i -r $wid -e 1,0,0,$xmid,$ymid

#xterm -title "term h" & pid=$!
sakura --title="term h" & pid=$!
sleep 0.5
wid=$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$pid" | cut "-d " -f1)
sleep 1
echo $pid $wid
wmctrl -i -r $wid -e 1,$((xmid+vdockw)),0,$xmid,$ymid
```

I tested that it works in two installed 18.04 LTS systems, Lubuntu (as it is) and in standard Ubuntu (with `vdockw=68`).

The shellscript uses the program packages `sakura wmctrl` and maybe `xterm`, which are available from the repository `universe` and can be installed with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sakura wmctrl xterm
```