# Open a new instance of gnome-system-monitor

Tags: gnome, xubuntu

I am running xubuntu 14.04.03 (ubuntu + xfce4) and use the gnome-system-monitor to check the processor and memory load, as well as get an overview of the running processes.

I struggle to open multiple instances of that tool. Simple calling `gnome-system-monitor` from different terminal windows does not help. It also does not have any sort of "new instance" options. And according to this question -- [Run true multiple process instances of gnome-terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal) -- it is a general problem with gnome applications. 
That answer provides a solution that should assign an `--app-id` to the gnome-terminal. That does not seem to work with the `gnome-system-monitor`.

I am wondering if there is an option to run any application in a new instance regardless of its options. I would want the system monitor to be assigned to a hotkey and pop-up on the current workspace in a new instance. Is there a command for that? Like `exec gnome-system-monitor --new-instance`.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no `app-id` in this case... You'll have to wait for `gnome-system-monitor` to be fully ported to [`gapplication`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gapplication-tool.html) and hope that one of the actions will be `new-window`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is slow but I had the same problem and solved it this way:

1. Open system monitor using whatever method (`gnome-system-monitor`).
2. Open the next instance with `sudo` (`sudo gnome-system-monitor`).

This only gives you two instances but for me that is enough. I automated it with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-system-monitor &
printf '<PASSWORD>\n' | sudo -S gnome-system-monitor
```

It isn't ideal that the password is in the file but at least you can make sure that no other users on the system can read the file.

Comment: Ha! That's a good one

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweak to the already existing answer, so that it's one command and without hanging + with themes (find in `gnome-tweaks` or in `/usr/share/themes` as by default it's white)

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup sudo -H 'GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark' gnome-system-monitor &
GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark nohup gnome-system-monitor &
```