# How to use `gnome-terminal` with new client/server architecture as wrapper?

Tags: shell-script, vim, gnome-terminal, gvim

Anyone knows how to accommodate for new `gnome-terminal-server` magic?

Before `gnome-terminal` got its new "client/server" architecture I used to use it as `vim` wrapper with great success for many years. Since `--disable-factory` got dropped the following code doesn't lock the process (due to forking) therefore it's useless as an editor for e.g. text areas in browser:

```
#!/bin/bash
TERMINAL=gnome-terminal
TERMARGS="--disable-factory --full-screen -e"

for ARG in "$@"; do
    # arguments quotation, etc.
    ARGS="$ARGS $ARG"
done

$TERMINAL $TERMARGS "vim $ARGS"
```

Comment: What if you start another terminal server (and use your stuff in [a new client inside that server](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201915))...

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/run-true-multiple-process-instances-of-gnome-terminal/201915#201915 ?

Comment: Did any of you actually try that? It doesn't work. Server just dies after 10 seconds no matter what I do. And if I try to open a terminal in newly created server, it doesn't spawn any windows - the `gnome-terminal` process just locks until `gnome-terminal-server` dies.

Comment: If I somehow manage to spawn a `gnome-terminal` window with `--app-id` parameter, I have a feeling, it will not lock the wrapper execution anyway. The idea is for the wrapper to wait until the terminal closes so it could only then give the control back to the parent.

Comment: A related question is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/ .

Comment: Yeah, and as I commented on that question on Aug 29 and 30, it doesn't work. So unless someone gives me a working example, I'm stuck with the old version `--disable-factory` merge.

Comment: https://chrisirwin.ca/posts/multiple-instances-of-gnome-terminal/  Looks helpful... if you're okay with some root-permission setup.

Comment: Ahh... You see I asked that question long time ago and by now I remember getting even further than what Chris Irwin describes on his blog, still, with no success as it never locked the process and therefore `gnome-terminal` remains useless as a wrapper. They simply removed that functionality.