# How to open the gnome-terminal within the gnome-terminal without disowning

Tags: process, gnome-terminal, disown

If I open the gnome-terminal within the gnome-terminal, the newly created terminal automatically gets disowned from the parent.

[image: Opening the gnome-terminal within the gnome-terminal]

Some other applications do not.

[image: Opening notepadqq in the gnome-terminal]

How to simulate that behavior?
How to not disown the new created terminal?

Thanks for your attention.

**EDIT:** For some reason, if I add the '--disable-factory' flag I get exactly the effect I want to get. Maybe there is something wrong with my config files.

Comment: That is _not_ in fact what GNOME Terminal is doing.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304269/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226465/ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323663/

Comment: To simulate that behavior you'll have to [start a new server and create terminals inside the newly created server.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201915/22142)

Comment: cheers for '--disable-factory' making it work.

Answer (score 1):

On newer gnome versions (tested on gnome 44), the solution to this is:

`gnome-terminal --wait`

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking to do is run the program in the "background". This can be done using the ampersand symbol (`&`) after the command:

```
$ notepadqq &
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the user wants. They want to start `gnome-terminal` "in the foreground".

Comment: My mistake. You are right @Kusalananda.