# How can we find out the pseudoterminal master and slave from each other?

Tags: pty, pseudoterminal, pts

A pseudoterminal has a pair of master and slave.

How can we find out the master device file from a slave device file (e.g. `/etc/pts/3`)? I only find `/dev/ptmx` and `/dev/pts/ptmx`, but they can't be shared by multiple slaves.

Given one of the processes working on the master and slave, how can we find out the other? 
For example, `ps` provides information about the controlling tty of each process.  Can it be helpful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

That is one thing that is harder than it should be.

With newer linux kernels, the index of the slave pty paired with a master can be gathered from the `tty-index` entry from `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD`. See this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d01c3289e7d68162e32bc08c2b65dd1a216a7ef8).

With older kernels, the only way you can get that is by attaching with a debugger to a process holding a master pty, and call `ptsname(3)` (or directly `ioctl(TIOCGPTN)`) on the file descriptor.

[but both methods will run into issues on systems using multiple devpts mounts, see below]

With that info, you can build a list of master-slave pairings, which will also allow you to look up the master starting up from the slave.

Here is a silly script that should do that; it will first try the `tty-index` way, and if that doesn't work it will fall back to `gdb`. For the latter case, it needs a **working** `gdb` (not `gdb-minimal` or another half-broken `gdb` most distros ship with) and because of its use of `gdb`, it will be **very slow**.

For each pty pair, it will print something like:

```
/dev/pts/1
    1227  3     t/ct_test
        1228  +*      t/ct_test
        1230  +      t/ct_test
/dev/pts/3
    975   9     'sshd: root [priv]' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
    978   14,18,19   'sshd: root@pts/3' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
        979   -*0,1,2,255   -bash
        1222  1     tiocsti
        1393  -0,1,2   sleep 3600
        1231  +0,2   perl ptys.pl
        1232  +1,2   cut -b1-60
```

the two `sshd` processes (pids 975 and 978) have open handles to the master side (one as its 9 fd and the other as its 14, 18 and 19 fds). `sleep` and `-bash` have open handles to the slave side as their standard (0,1 and 2) fds. The session leader (`bash`) is also marked with a `*`, the processes in the foreground (`perl` and `cut`) with a `+`, and those in the background (`less` and `-bash`) with a `-`.

The `t/ct_test` processes are using the pty as their controlling terminal without having any fd open to it. `tiocsti` has an open handle to it without it being its controlling terminal.

Tested on Debian 9 and Fedora 28. Info about the magic numbers it's using can be found in [`procfs(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [`Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2339e91d0e6609e17943a0ab3c3c8c4044760c05/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt#L2084) in the linux kernel source.

---

This will fail on any system using chroots or namespace containers; that's not fixable without some changes to the kernel, since there's no reliable way to match the `tty` field from `/proc/PID/stat` to a pty, and a fd opened via `/dev/ptmx` to the corresponding `/dev/pts` mount. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541531/308316) for a rant about it.

This will also not link in any fd opened via `/dev/tty`; the *real* tty could be worked out by attaching to the process and calling `ioctl(fd, TIOCGDEV, &dev)`, but that will mean another dirty heavy use of gdb, and it will run into the same issues as above with the major, minor numbers being ambiguous for pseudo-tty slaves.

**ptys.pl:**

```perl
my (%pty, %ctty);
for(</proc/*[0-9]*/{fd/*,stat}>){
    if(my ($pid, $fd) = m{/proc/(\d+)/fd/(\d+)}){
        next unless -c $_;
        my $rdev = (stat)[6]; my $maj = $rdev >> 8 & 0xfff;
        if($rdev == 0x502){ # /dev/ptmx or /dev/pts/ptmx
            $pty{ptsname($pid, $fd, readlink $_)}{m}{$pid}{$fd} = 1;
        }elsif($maj >= 136 && $maj <= 143){ # /dev/pts/N
            $pty{readlink $_}{s}{$pid}{$fd} = 1;
        }
    }else{
        my @s = readfile($_) =~ /(?<=\().*(?=\))|[^\s()]+/gs;
        $ctty{$s[6]}{$s[0]} =       # ctty{tty}{pid} =
            ($s[4] == $s[7] ? '+' : '-').   # pgrp == tpgid
            ($s[0] == $s[5] ? '*' : '');    # pid == sid
    }
}
for(sort {length($a)<=>length($b) or $a cmp $b} keys %pty){
    print "$_\n";
    pproc(4, $pty{$_}{m}); pproc(8, $pty{$_}{s}, $ctty{(stat)[6]});
}

sub readfile { local $/; my $h; open $h, '<', shift and <$h> }
sub cmdline {
    join ' ', map { s/'/'\\''/g, $_ = "'$_'" if m{^$|[^\w./+=-]}; $_ }
        readfile("/proc/$_[0]/cmdline") =~ /([^\0]*)\0/g;
}
sub pproc {
    my ($px, $h, $sinfo) = @_;
    exists $$h{$_} or $$h{$_} = {''} for keys %$sinfo;
    return printf "%*s???\n", $px, "" unless $h;
    for my $pid (sort {$a<=>$b} keys %$h){
        printf "%*s%-5d %s%-3s   %s\n", $px, "", $pid, $$sinfo{$pid},
            join(',', sort {$a<=>$b} keys %{$$h{$pid}}),
            cmdline $pid;
    }
}
sub ptsname {
    my ($pid, $fd, $ptmx) = @_;
    return '???' unless defined(my $ptn = getptn($pid, $fd));
    $ptmx =~ m{(.*)(?:/pts)?/ptmx$} ? "$1/pts/$ptn" : "$ptmx ..?? pts/$ptn"
}
sub getptn {
    my ($pid, $fd) = @_;
    return $1 if
        readfile("/proc/$pid/fdinfo/$fd") =~ /^tty-index:\s*(\d+)$/m;
    return gdb_ioctl($pid, $fd, 0x80045430);    # TIOCGPTN
}
sub gdb_ioctl {
    my ($pid, $fd, $ioctl) = @_;
    my $cmd = qq{p (int)ioctl($fd, $ioctl, &errno) ? -1 : errno};
    qx{exec 3>&1; gdb -batch -p $pid -ex '$cmd' 2>&1 >&3 |
            grep -v '/sysdeps/.*No such file or directory' >&2}
        =~ /^\$1 *= *(\d+)$/m ? $1 : undef;
}
```

Comment: Nice... Just curious, how does `gdb` tend to be broken, as shipped in distros?

Comment: Thanks. Given one of the processes working on the master and slave, how can we find out the other?

Comment: Thanks. sorry, could you tell me how to run your script? I don't know perl.

Comment: @Tim `perl ptys.pl`

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, using `devpts`, there is no master device file. The process on the master end uses a file descriptor, which it gets by opening `ptmx`, but there’s no corresponding device node.

See [the `ptmx` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/ptmx.4.html) for details.

(With BSD-style `pty`s on Linux, there are matching device pairs, such as `/dev/ptyp1` and `/dev/ttyp1`, respectively on the master and slave side.)

Comment: Thanks. Given one of the processes working on the master and slave, how can we find out the other?

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492753/why-are-dev-ptmx-and-dev-pts-ptmx-not-device-files

Comment: This seems like a new thing, maybe a year or so. I have a script that uses `chroot` that started to fail because `dev/pts` was not mounted. Thanks to your answer I was able to figure that out <3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `lsof +E` gives you information of both ends of FDs, including ptm/pts.