# Run a script in a new terminal window, but the same terminal emulator as the current window

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal

I want to run a script in a new terminal window. I found several solutions such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/215483/how-can-i-open-a-new-terminal-window-from-a-terminal-in-linux). However, they all provide terminal specific solutions. So `konsole ./myscript.sh` works if I'm using konsole, but not if I'm using gnome-terminal or some other terminal program.

Is there a way to open a new terminal that is of the same type as the current one? Or equivalently, a way to locate the executable for the currently running terminal? Or am I misunderstanding something and this doesn't make sense in general, and I should just hardcode a few specific options.

I primarily use arch, debian, and ubuntu, so if there is a solution that works on just those three that would be fine, albeit suboptimal.

Comment: I don't think there's any general solution to that. A quick and dirty solution is to guess the name of the terminal from the parent proces: `case $(cat /proc/$PPID/comm) in gnome-*) ... ;; konsole*) ...;; esac` (you cannot use the command name directly with gnome, since gnome-terminal does not start itself a shell process, but asks `gnome-terminal-server` to do it for it.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492302/how-can-we-find-out-the-pseudoterminal-master-and-slave-from-each-other

Comment: There's also the `$WINDOWID` environment variable (which could allow you to get the name of the terminal command via the `_NET_WM_PID` or `WM_COMMAND` properties), but it's not set by gnome-terminal.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'll try to guess it from that, and if that fails, fallback onto a hardcoded solution.