# How are PAM sessions applied to systemd user services?

Tags: systemd

Each time you log in in as a user, you get a new PAM session.  E.g. I believe people have used `pam_group` to [add your session's processes to groups for access to certain devices](https://debian-administration.org/article/308/Giving_power_to_the_user_in_front_of_the_screen), if you log on to a local terminal.

`pam_systemd` starts one `systemd --user` instance, which is shared between all the user's login sessions.  Nowadays, e.g. in Fedora 26, you will see all gnome-terminal processes are actually started by `systemd --user`.  So that's where your terminal commands run.  They do not run in the systemd session scopes that are created for each individual login...

How is the single `systemd --user` instance, and the processes it creates, affected by the PAM sessions?

Comment: For more on the GNOME Terminal side of things, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/ and linked questions+answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pam_systemd is documented as starting `systemd --user` using `user@.service`.

`user@.service` uses `PAMName=`, so it runs inside a dedicated PAM session.  `pam_systemd` has a special-case for `PAMName=systemd-user`, so that starting `user@.service` does not recurse infinitely or deadlock.  (Also this process doesn't get put in a new session scope unit).

```
$ systemctl cat user@
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service

[Unit]
Description=User Manager for UID %i
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
User=%i
PAMName=systemd-user
Type=notify
ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
Slice=user-%i.slice
KillMode=mixed
Delegate=yes
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStopSec=120s
```

---

pam_systemd does not really work with features tied to the PAM session  that vary based on the individual TTY.   Instead, `logind` uses ACLs to grant the logged in *user* access to certain devices.  As long as the PAM session is open, *any* process with that UID will be able to access them.

logind also has a DBus interface which allows one process of that user to open certain devices, intended for the display server e.g. X Windows.  It has code to handle switching VTs, and multiple "seats" (groups of devices).